# Twitter::Error::Unauthorized in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm building an app in ruby, and I want to fetch my followers. It keeps telling me:

```
Twitter::Error::Unauthorized in HomeController#index 
Could not authenticate you
```

This is my code:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = "ONJKJHkWOD3ZFhjrVpx3Rw"
config.consumer_secret     = "myTVu2slmYfPcToNOfQb8HV4ECciAeCAor0VPD37Sc"
config.access_token        = "225985017-UjKFFh7fSQPSnKQWRM63wxXzW2ufu8g8z5RjLcNt"
config.access_token_secret = "WRQE66s4ez9mCVuwXzljaHnK9YvRecnPpfaZIlolAKFeN"
end

myfile = File.new("write.txt", "w")

count=0
cursor1=-1

while (cursor1 != 0) do
@followers =client.followers("riyadcarioca","cursor"=>"#{cursor1}")
cursor1=@followers.next_cursor
users=@followers.users
puts count
 users.each do |follower|
   count+=1
    myfile.puts "\"#{count}\",\"#{follower.name}\",\"#{follower.screen_name}\",\"#   {follower.url}\",\"#{follower.followers_count}\",\"#{follower.location}\",\"#{follower.created_at}\",\"#{follower.description}\",\"#{follower.friends_count}\",\"#{follower.lang}\",\"#{follower.time_zone}\",\"#{follower.verified}\""
 end
 sleep(5)
end
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't write here your oauth credentials, with that people can see everything about you account, including tweets, private messagges, (depending on your permissions), etc...
2. Try regenerating your access tokens.
3. Sometimes twitter takes time to update your account tokens when you generate them from the dev app page, go and see if the tokens haven't change.